# in nodejs, how to use 'require' in a function created with 'new Function'

Tags: node.js, require

I'm writing a nodejs view template.
Somewhere I have code like this:

```
var fnStr = "var moment = require('moment'); moment(new Date);";
var fn = new Function('data', fnStr);
fn();
```

then, I got error "ReferenceError: require is not defined".

I checked Node API, It says

```
require isn't actually a global but rather local to each module
```

Now my own solution is set:

```
global.require = require;
```

Any better solutions?

Comment: where are you executing fn() that require is undefined? is it in the browser?

Comment: @Russ, I run it in node environment, not in browser